Trying to draw box around checkbox and display text using pdfbox
Trying to create a PDF fillable form using java 8 and pdfbox  2.0.30 .
For each topping I want a checkbox with a box drawn around it and the topping. Seems pretty simple.
Code executes and viewing the resulting toppingsForm.pdf in a browser shows

checkboxes with boxes drawn around them but no topping
OR
checkboxes with toppings but with no box drawn around the checkbox

    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
    
    import org.apache.pdfbox.*;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.util.*;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.*;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.*;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDRectangle;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDColor;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDDeviceRGB;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.form.PDFormXObject;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.*;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAnnotationWidget;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAppearanceDictionary;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAppearanceEntry;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAppearanceStream;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDBorderStyleDictionary;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.*;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.text.*;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.*;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.*;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.io.*;
    
    public class Toppings {
    
        private static float getLineWidth( PDAnnotationWidget widget) {
            
            PDBorderStyleDictionary bs = widget.getBorderStyle();
            if( bs != null) {
                return bs.getWidth();
            }
            return 1;
        }
        
        private static void drawRect( PDDocument document, PDPage page, PDRectangle rect) {
            try {
                PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true);
     
                float ll_x = rect.getLowerLeftX();
                float ll_y = rect.getLowerLeftY();
                float height = rect.getHeight();
                float length = rect.getWidth();
                
                contentStream.addRect( ll_x, ll_y, height, length);
                contentStream.setLineWidth(1);
                contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(Color.WHITE);
                contentStream.setStrokingColor(Color.BLACK);
                contentStream.stroke();
                contentStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
        // Generate Form Labels
        private static void addText( PDDocument document, PDPage page, String myText, float x, float y, boolean bold) {
     
            try {
                PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true);
                contentStream.beginText(); 
                contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA, 6);
                if( bold) {
                    contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD, 6);
                }
                contentStream.newLineAtOffset(x, y);
                contentStream.showText(myText);      
                contentStream.endText();
                contentStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
        private static void addCheckbox( PDDocument pdfDoc, PDAcroForm acroForm, PDPage page, String name, float x, float y) {
            
            try {            
                PDCheckBox checkbox = new PDCheckBox(acroForm);
                checkbox.setPartialName( name);
                
                PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary appearanceCharacteristics = new PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary(new COSDictionary());
                appearanceCharacteristics.setBorderColour(new PDColor(new float[] { 1, 0, 0 }, PDDeviceRGB.INSTANCE));
                appearanceCharacteristics.setBackground(  new PDColor(new float[]{0, 1, 0.3f}, PDDeviceRGB.INSTANCE));
                appearanceCharacteristics.setNormalCaption("4");
                
                PDBorderStyleDictionary borderStyleDictionary = new PDBorderStyleDictionary();
                borderStyleDictionary.setWidth(1);
                borderStyleDictionary.setStyle(PDBorderStyleDictionary.STYLE_SOLID);
    
                PDAnnotationWidget widget = new PDAnnotationWidget();
                widget.setRectangle( new PDRectangle( x, y, 16, 16) );
                drawRect( pdfDoc, page, widget.getRectangle());        // comment out this line and toppings appear
                widget.setAnnotationFlags(4);
                widget.setBorderStyle(borderStyleDictionary);
                widget.setPage( page);
                widget.setParent( checkbox);
                
                List<PDAnnotationWidget> widgets = new ArrayList<>();
                widgets.add(widget);
                page.getAnnotations().add(widget);
                checkbox.setWidgets(widgets);
                
                acroForm.getFields().add(checkbox);
                
                addText(  pdfDoc, page, name, x + 20, y + 6, false);  // comment out this line and checkbox outlines appear
     
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
              
        private static void addToppings( PDDocument pdfDoc, PDAcroForm acroForm, PDPage page, float x, float y) throws IOException {
            
            List<String> options = Arrays.asList("pepperoni","sausage","ham"
                                                ,"chicken","canadian bacon","mushrooms"
                                                ,"pineapple","onions","green pepper"
                                                ,"red pepper","black olives","green olives");
    
            for( int i = 0; i < 12; i++ ) {
                addCheckbox( pdfDoc, acroForm, page, options.get(i), x, y);
                y = y - 20;
            }    
        }        
        
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                PDDocument pdfDoc = new PDDocument();  // outfile
                PDPage page = new PDPage();
                pdfDoc.addPage(page);
                PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream( pdfDoc, page);
                PDAcroForm acroForm = new PDAcroForm( pdfDoc);

                float x = 20;
                float y = 500;
                addToppings( pdfDoc, acroForm, page, x, y);
                
                contentStream.close();
                pdfDoc.save("C:/Users/MainUser/toppingsForm.pdf");
                pdfDoc.close();
            } catch ( IOException e) {
                e.getMessage();
            }
        }
    
    }

My first time using pdfBox to create forms, am usually filling them in.
Maybe there's some subtle sizing/overlap issue I'm bumping in to. Or a better way altogether, like  setting a visible border on the checkbox itself.
TIA,
Still-learning Steve

1- add pdfDoc.getDocumentCatalog().setAcroForm(acroForm); near the end
2- keep drawRect() but remove contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(Color.WHITE); because this means your text is in white.
3- add this below checkbox.setWidgets(widgets);
widget.setAppearanceCharacteristics(appearanceCharacteristics);
PDAppearanceDictionary ap = new PDAppearanceDictionary();
widget.setAppearance(ap);
PDAppearanceEntry normalAppearance = ap.getNormalAppearance();
COSDictionary normalAppearanceDict = (COSDictionary) normalAppearance.getCOSObject();
normalAppearanceDict.setItem(COSName.Off, createAppearanceStream(pdfDoc, widget, false));
normalAppearanceDict.setItem(COSName.YES, createAppearanceStream(pdfDoc, widget, true));

4- add this:
private static PDAppearanceStream createAppearanceStream(
        final PDDocument document, PDAnnotationWidget widget, boolean on) throws IOException
{
    PDRectangle rect = widget.getRectangle();
    PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary appearanceCharacteristics;
    PDAppearanceStream yesAP = new PDAppearanceStream(document);
    yesAP.setBBox(new PDRectangle(rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight()));
    yesAP.setResources(new PDResources());
    PDPageContentStream yesAPCS = new PDPageContentStream(document, yesAP);
    appearanceCharacteristics = widget.getAppearanceCharacteristics();
    PDColor backgroundColor = appearanceCharacteristics.getBackground();
    PDColor borderColor = appearanceCharacteristics.getBorderColour();
    float lineWidth = getLineWidth(widget);
    yesAPCS.setLineWidth(lineWidth); // border style (dash) ignored
    yesAPCS.setNonStrokingColor(backgroundColor);
    yesAPCS.addRect(0, 0, rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
    yesAPCS.fill();
    yesAPCS.setStrokingColor(borderColor);
    yesAPCS.addRect(lineWidth / 2, lineWidth / 2, rect.getWidth() - lineWidth, rect.getHeight() - lineWidth);
    yesAPCS.stroke();
    if (!on)
    {
        yesAPCS.close();
        return yesAP;
    }

    yesAPCS.addRect(lineWidth, lineWidth, rect.getWidth() - lineWidth * 2, rect.getHeight() - lineWidth * 2);
    yesAPCS.clip();

    String normalCaption = appearanceCharacteristics.getNormalCaption();
    if (normalCaption == null)
    {
        normalCaption = "4"; // Adobe behaviour
    }
    if ("8".equals(normalCaption))
    {
        // Adobe paints a cross instead of using the Zapf Dingbats cross symbol
        yesAPCS.setStrokingColor(0f);
        yesAPCS.moveTo(lineWidth * 2, rect.getHeight() - lineWidth * 2);
        yesAPCS.lineTo(rect.getWidth() - lineWidth * 2, lineWidth * 2);
        yesAPCS.moveTo(rect.getWidth() - lineWidth * 2, rect.getHeight() - lineWidth * 2);
        yesAPCS.lineTo(lineWidth * 2, lineWidth * 2);
        yesAPCS.stroke();
    }
    else
    {
        Rectangle2D bounds = new Rectangle2D.Float();
        String unicode = null;

        // ZapfDingbats font may be missing or substituted, let's use AFM resources instead.
        AFMParser parser = new AFMParser(PDType1Font.class.getResourceAsStream(
                "/org/apache/pdfbox/resources/afm/ZapfDingbats.afm"));
        FontMetrics metric = parser.parse();
        for (CharMetric cm : metric.getCharMetrics())
        {
            // The caption is not unicode, but the Zapf Dingbats code in the PDF.
            // Assume that only the first character is used.
            if (normalCaption.codePointAt(0) == cm.getCharacterCode())
            {
                BoundingBox bb = cm.getBoundingBox();
                bounds = new Rectangle2D.Float(bb.getLowerLeftX(), bb.getLowerLeftY(), 
                                               bb.getWidth(), bb.getHeight());
                unicode = PDType1Font.ZAPF_DINGBATS.getGlyphList().toUnicode(cm.getName());
                break;
            }
        }
        if (bounds.isEmpty())
        {
            throw new IOException("Bounds rectangle for chosen glyph is empty");
        }
        float size = (float) Math.min(bounds.getWidth(), bounds.getHeight()) / 1000;
        // assume that checkmark has square size
        // the calculations approximate what Adobe is doing, i.e. put the glyph in the middle
        float fontSize = (rect.getWidth() - lineWidth * 2) / size * 0.6666f;
        float xOffset = (float) (rect.getWidth() - (bounds.getWidth()) / 1000 * fontSize) / 2;
        xOffset -= bounds.getX() / 1000 * fontSize;
        float yOffset = (float) (rect.getHeight() - (bounds.getHeight()) / 1000 * fontSize) / 2;
        yOffset -= bounds.getY() / 1000 * fontSize;
        yesAPCS.setNonStrokingColor(0f);
        yesAPCS.beginText();
        yesAPCS.setFont(PDType1Font.ZAPF_DINGBATS, fontSize);
        yesAPCS.newLineAtOffset(xOffset, yOffset);
        yesAPCS.showText(unicode);
        yesAPCS.endText();
    }
    yesAPCS.close();
    return yesAP;
}

(3) and (4) are from the CreateCheckBox example; I suspect you used parts of it.
5- (update) looking at the example, it turns out you don't need drawRect() at all. Instead, add checkbox.unCheck(); after the line checkbox.setWidgets(widgets);. This makes sure that the checkbox in a defined state.

Looks like this fits the bill. Indeed I did blatantly borrow chunks from the example listed.... is there a way to "group" these boxes logically, like a PDWidgetGroup or something ?

Maybe you mean a radio buttons? There you can have a group of buttons and only one of these can be selected. For example if you'd allow only one type of olives. There is a different example for that: https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/2.0/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/interactive/form/CreateRadioButtons.java?view=markup

radio buttons or checkboxes within a group would work for none-or-only-one scenario like crust:small/medium/large   .  But toppings, if grouped, would need to be multi-select as described here https://help.goformz.com/en/articles/4776805-about-checkbox-group-fields  . I could kludge this with naming conventions  i.e. checkbox.setPartialName("toppings_green_olives")  and accompanying label "green olives"

That website is either not related to PDF, or they use PDF but with Javascript.

Yes, there are (usually) many paths to the top of the mountain. If only there were markers.... seems like a iterating over a OrderedHashMap<String,String>   "toppings_green_olives","green olives" ... would do the trick ... then the (python) script that -reads- the form could do some comprehension-fu based on [widg for widg in list_widg where  widg.field_value == "Yes"]
